# Why this error is showing 0x80246002 while installing the update?

Tags: update, insider-preview

I got the error  0x80246002 while updating the phone and download is at 0%. Why is this occurring.Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to update to build 10512? What model is your phone?

Comment: Nokia lumia 630

Answer (score 2):

download progress has a bug , but it's downloading in background. after several min turn off you wifi and then turn off your mobile , then turn on you mobile and wifi and go to update place and check its progress percent.